# Odd Interaction with Select / Option and findAll

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I've been trying to pull data from some HTML, but I've been struggling to find a solution with this Select / Option.

```
<select name = "Name1">    
<option>String1
<option>String2
<option>String3
<option>String4
<option>String5
<option>String6
</option></option></option></option></option></option></select>
```

Everything I've tried so far either returns an empty array or a huge array including differing amounts of `</option>`s

If possible, I'd like for it to return

```
[String1, String2, String3, String4, String5, String6]
```

Comment: Where did you get that HTML from? It shouldn't be like that.

Comment: Meanwhile, please give us a [mcve]—the a complete sample that includes the code you tried that returns that huge array, and the sample input you tried it against (which might just be what you already have—as long as it really does provide the output you're asking about), and we can help you debug it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

data = '''
<select name = "Name1">    
<option>String1
<option>String2
<option>String3
<option>String4
<option>String5
<option>String6
</option></option></option></option></option></option></select>
'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'html.parser')
for i in soup.find_all('option'):
    print(str(i.text).split('\n')[:-1])
    break
```

Output:

```
['String1', 'String2', 'String3', 'String4', 'String5', 'String6']
```